# Как из элементов массива строк создать тип-объединение из элементов данного массива?

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Предположим есть массив строк ['id', 'logo', 'mom', 'dad', 'somethingelse'], из него нужно получить объединение типов элементов массива, причем не string|string|string|... ,а 'id'|'logo'|'mom'|... . Соответственно интересует вопрос: как это сделать с произвольным массивом строк. Можно ли это как-то организовать через mapped types или что-то еще может?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const ARRAY_STRING = ['id', 'logo', 'mom', 'dad', 'somethingelse'] as const;
type ArrayStringVariant = typeof ARRAY_STRING[number];
```